# How to set different colour in Grafana XY chart for distinct values from a specific column

Tags: grafana, scatter-plot

I have a table in postgres and the data looks like below:

[postgres data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhQWK.png)

Now, I have created a XY chart with x-axis as "unique_value" and y-axis as "value". And for the points, "location".

Please help in differentiating each location in different color. Example: 110 (repeated 3 times) locations in red, 110 (repeated 2 times) locations in green, 116 (repeated 2 times) locations in purple, and so on.

I now have the below chart

[Grafana dashboard - XY chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iunBS.png)

Thanks for the reply!!